# Log update issue while running python log via robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Issue: Unable to get all the log types printed in console and none at log file while invoking below log methods via robot files.

```
import logging
from colorlog import ColoredFormatter

class Log():
    LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
    LOGFORMAT = "  %(log_color)s%(levelname)-8s%(reset)s | %(log_color)s%(message)s%(reset)s"
    logging.root.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    formatter = ColoredFormatter(LOGFORMAT)
    stream = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    stream.setFormatter(formatter)
    Log = logging.getLogger('pythonConfig')
    Log.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    Log.addHandler(stream)

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename='c://foo//app.log',
        format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO,
    )

    @classmethod
    def warn(cls, message):
        cls.Log.warning(message)

    @classmethod
    def info(cls, message):
        cls.Log.info(message)

    @classmethod
    def error(cls, message):
        cls.Log.error(message)

    @classmethod
    def debug(cls, message):
        cls.Log.debug(message)

# Calling class methods

Log.warn("test")
Log.info("test")
Log.error("test")
Log.debug("test")
```

**Running using python from command prompt:-**

```
C:foo>py log.py

  WARNING  | test
  INFO     | test
  ERROR    | test
  DEBUG    | test
```

**app.log**

```
01-Sep-19 21:32:31 - WARNING: test
01-Sep-19 21:32:31 - INFO: test
01-Sep-19 21:32:31 - ERROR: test
01-Sep-19 21:32:31 - DEBUG: test
```

When I invoke the same methods via robot file (Python >> Robot suite), I am unable to get any of the logs printed in log file (app.log) and could see only error and warning messages are printed in console. could someone help me in this regards?

**Runner.py**

```
import robot

logFile = open('c:\\foo\\ExecutionReport.txt','w')
htmlpath = "c:\\foo\\Reports.html"
robot.run("c:\\foo\\test_sample.robot", log=None,report=htmlpath, output=None,
          stdout=logFile)
```

**Robot:-**

```
*** Settings ***
Library  ../Robot/Log.py

*** Test Cases ***
testinglogger
    info  test
    error  test
    debug  test
    warn  test
```

**app.log:**
None

[image]

Comment: could someone help me on this regards?

Comment: Any assistance?

Answer (score 1):

In the Python `Runner.py` script you are invoking the `robot.run` function and setting some parameters for the execution, such as `log=None` and `output=None`. This causes no log files to be created (no output) and no logging to be visible (outside of `ERROR` and `WARN` apparently.).

See these Robot Framework run parameters:

`-o --output file` where file is the name of the Robot output. Setting `NONE` to this causes also reports and all other file logging to be disabled.

Leave unassigned to create default log files for Robot Framework. I believe this maps to the `robot.run` command's `output` parameter.

`-L --loglevel level` where level is the desired lowest logging level.

Available levels: `TRACE`, `DEBUG`, `INFO` (default), `WARN`, `NONE` (no logging). In this case you probably want to set it to `DEBUG`

Make the required changes to your `Runner.py` script and try again :)

Here is the complete documentation for the latest version `3.1.2` Robot Framework's `robot.run` script:

https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1.2/_modules/robot/run.html

Comment: I have edited as per your suggestion but still not getting log file updated robot.run("C:\\foo\\test_sample.robot", log=log, report=report, output=output, loglevel=logging.DEBUG, stdout=exec_report)

Comment: Any further assistance?